# First two conditions of the Ols estimate

Tags: self-study, econometrics

this was a question in my previous test. The answer given to this is 'd'. But from what I know the option given in 'b' are the two first order conditions of calculating an ordinary least squared estimate of $u_i$ (which is $\hat{u}_i$).

should the answer be 'd' or 'b'? Why?

Consider the following classical linear regression of y on x,

$y_i = βx_i + u_i$

$i = 1, 2, ..., n$

where $E(u_i) = 0$, $V (u_i) = σ^2$
for all i, and u
′
i
s are homoscedastic and
non-autocorrelated. Now, let ˆui be the ordinary least square estimate
of ui

Then which of the following statements is true?

a) $\sum \hat{u}_i = 0$

b) $\sum  \hat{u}_i = 0$ and $\sum x_i\hat{u}_i = 0$

c)$\sum  \hat{u}_i = 0$ and $\sum x_i \hat{u}_i \neq 0$

d) $\sum x_i \hat{u}_i = 0$

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag and read the tag [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Consider the $(x,y)$ dataset $(0,1), (1,1).$  By inspection--no calculation is needed--you can immediately determine the $\hat u_i.$  Which of (a) - (d) are true for this dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Option (d) is already true in least squares. It's also present in (b). The difference between the two is about the *sum of residuals*. And, it is $0$ when you have a *bias term* in your model, because when you do, you can think of $x_i$ corresponding to it as all $1$'s, which lead to $$\sum \hat{u}_ix_i=\sum \hat{u}_i.1=\sum \hat{u}_i=0$$.

Comment: sorry, I dont understand the explanation.  could you elaborate?

Comment: i did however found that if the regression does not contain a constant/intercept term, the sum of error terms may not be zero. so the only option left is (d). which is the result that Xi are not correlated with the error terms.

Comment: doesnt having bias in the erros mean E(u) =/= 0? but since they do state that this is not the case, why have we rejected this?

Comment: Well, $E[u_i]$ and $\sum \hat{u_i}$ are not the same thing. One is sum, the other is the mean. The optimization enforces that we have $\sum \hat{u_i}x_i=0$. This is true each regressor. When you have the bias term, one of your regressors becomes $z_i=1$. And, $\sum \hat{u_i}z_i=\sum \hat{u_i} .1 = 0$

Comment: (d) is not an assumption: it is a statement of the *Normal Equations* of least squares regression.